# Method Not Found Caliburn Micro (DataContext issue?)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a UserControl (MainView) that has a viewbox on it to display another UserControl (MidView) and inside that UserControl I have a canvas that shows another UserControl (BottomView). On the grandchild UserControl (BottomView) I have a ListBox that I want to be able to rightclick and call a particular method.

I have

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseRightButtonDown] = [Action Method1]"
```

on the ListBox but whenever I rightclick the box it checks the grandparents ViewModel (MainViewModel) for "Method1". I think I have to use cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext to get it to look in the BottomViewModel but I can't work out how to use it.

I thought

```
cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding MainView}"
```

or

```
cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding MainViewModel}"
```

would solve my problem but no luck. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I've found an old App where I did this for a right click `Context` menu on a `TreeView` and needed to execute a method on the actual selected item `ViewModel`, rather than the parent `ViewModel`.

I used:

```
<ContextMenu cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <MenuItem Header="Edit" cal:Message.Attach="Edit" />
    <!-- Other Menu Items -->
 </ContextMenu>
```

Hopefully similar logic will apply to your situation (using your desired event/method).